# Operation could not be completed when I try to play a video on my camera roll

Tags: ipod-touch, video, camera

I have a video recording on my iPod 4th generation and when I try to play it, it comes up with "Operation could not be completed" the recording was from 23rd November 2013 and I have tried many things since then and it still won't play. I have rebooted my iPod and I have sent the video via email to myself but I still cant play it. I dont want to delete this video as I know the video is important and I know where its from. What can I do to get it to play?

Comment: Where (in which applications) did you try to play the video? Does it work in the Photos/Videos app on the iPod? In the mail you sent yourself, how big is the video file?

Comment: There is a distinct possibility that the file your attempting to open has become corrupted and/or unreadable on the hard drive inside your iPod.  I would recommend syncing the iPod, first to delete the video from the device, then again to copy it back onto it.  See if it plays then.  Assuming you have the video on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use a VideoLan application.

It does not look like much but it works like charm and it is very easy to use.

You can download a Mac version [here](http://www.videolan.org/index.html).

Or in your case the iOS version [here](https://itunes.apple.com/app/vlc-ios/id650377962).

It is a Video player that plays anything, it's safe to use, and I had it for years and play all my videos on it.

Since the Video was send to you it might be in a format that your iPod can not play. So use the VideoLan.

Feel free to Donate, to those hard working programers.